# How to Convert Existing Android Studio project to multi-device-hybrid-apps for Visual Studio

Tags: android, native, hybrid, visual-studio-cordova

What are the steps to Convert existing Android project (developed in Android Studio) to multi-device hybrid apps in Visual Studio 2013?

Is there any Step-by-Step Guide available for Novice user to start from the scratch in multi-device hybrid apps in Visual Studio 2013?

How to use socket connection in multi-device hybrid apps in Visual Studio 2013?

-Dixit Solanki

Comment: You can use the documentation on the [landing page](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/cordova-vs.aspx) to get started with MDHA development. As for the question about Android Studio, are you asking how you can convert a Java project to a JavaScript cordova project?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert an Android Studio project to a Cordova project. Android Studio is native and uses Java, whereas Cordova uses HTML 5 and JavaScript. The native functionalities you get with Cordova is because browsers expose access to native APIs, which are explored by Cordova.

Just in case you don't know, Multi-Device Hybrid Apps is a new category of projects in Visual Studio and Cordova is the only option available for now.

Most of the documentation you can find about MDHA is in their [official website](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/cordova-vs.aspx). We can expect to find more information as this project gets more attention.

If you want to learn more about Cordova, you can [read their documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/), or take a look at [this book](http://phonegap.com/book/apache-cordova-3-programming/), or [this PluralSight course](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/creating-mobile-apps-hybrid-cross-platform-native).